# Ember reloading model of parent route when transitioning to a dynamic route

Tags: ember.js, routes, query-string

I'm currently experimenting with query parameters (though i dont think thats the problem here) and the problem i am seeing is that when i click on a row on a table to load a nested route the model of the table itself is reloading leading to poor performance

the map looks like this:

```
    this.resource("blockedLists", function() {
        this.resource('sellers', {queryParams : [ 'sort', 'ts', 'searchText','startNumber','resultsNumber', 'showWindow', 'showAll' ]}, function() {
            this.resource('selectedSeller', {queryParams : [ 'dp' ],path : ':id'}); 
        });
    });
```

when i link to the selectedSeller route, the model of the sellers route is loaded.

```
{{#link-to 'selectedSeller' id dp="true"}}  etc ....
```

I'm doing the ajax call in the model hook in the router class.  Every time i click on the link two Im seeing both selectedSeller and sellers route call their respective "model" hooks causing 2 ajax calls.

Am I doing something wrong? what causes ember to refresh the model?  I am currently using canary so I am expecting bugs but I'd like to confirm whether the problem is me first.

Thanks

Comment: if I were to guess I'd say it is trying to send `dp=true` to selectedSeller and `id` to sellers, I haven't messed with the query-params much yet, since it's still being hardened.  Does the link-to actually work (aka id and dp='true' goes to the selectedSeller route)?

Comment: the architechture has changed now so i guess this is no longer relevenant.  Yes it all works great apart from this small issue.